# c# replace odd elements of array with even elements of another array

Tags: c#, arrays

```
int[] array1 = new int[6] {2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 4};

int[] array2 = new int[6] {4, 8, 2, 1, 5, 8};
```

I want to change odd elements in first array with even elements in second.

Comment: Do you mean elements at odd/even index positions, or elements with odd/even values?

Comment: Show what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this is a very specific problem, here's a solution:

```
var array1 = new[] { 2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 4 };
var array2 = new [] { 4, 8, 2, 1, 5, 8 };

array1 = array1.Select((i, index) => i % 2 == 1 ? array2[index] : i).ToArray();
//result: int[6] { 2, 8, 2, 8, 5, 4 }
```

It takes the elements from the first array, checks wether it's even and replaces it if it's odd with the item at that position of the other array.

I'm not totally sure wether this is what you're looking for, otherwise kindly clarify your problem.

For example you could mean items with an odd index:

```
var array1 = new[] { 2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 4 };
var array2 = new[] { 4, 8, 2, 1, 5, 8 };

array1 = array1.Select((i, index) => index % 2 == 1 ? array2[index-1] : i).ToArray();
//result: int[6] { 2, 4, 7, 2, 9, 5 }
```

Comment: @EmrahIsmayilzade if this solved your problem, don't forget to mark the answer as an answer (tick the checkmark), as this will help you and the wider community to identify solved problems.

Answer (score 1):

Long version and different approach to the problem. **(Without Linq)**

```
int[] array1 = new int[6] { 2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 4 };
int[] array2 = new int[6] { 4, 8, 2, 1, 5, 8 };

for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++) 
{
 if ((array1[i] % 2 == 0)) 
 {
  array1[i] = array1[i];
 } 
 else 
 {
  array1[i] = array2[i];
 }
}

foreach(int t in array1)
 Console.Write(t + ", ");

//result: 2, 8, 2, 8, 5, 4
```

Comment: In this anti-Linq-example I see the beautiness in Linq once again :)

Comment: anti-Linq... Like old days :)